# What can go wrong in following code - and compile time requirements?

Tags: c++, pointers

first let me say I know the following code will be considered "bad" practices.. But I'm limited by the environment a "little" bit:

In an dynamic library I wish to use "pointers" (to point to classes) - however the program that will use this dll, can only pass & receive doubles. So I need to "fit" the pointer in a double. The following code tries to achieve this, which I hope to work in a 64-bit environment:

```
EXPORT double InitializeClass() {
    SampleClass* pNewObj = new SampleClass;
    double ret;
    unsigned long long tlong(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(pNewObj));
    memcpy(&ret, &tlong, sizeof(tlong));
    return ret;
}
EXPORT double DeleteClass(double i) {
    unsigned long long tlong;
    memcpy(&tlong, &i, sizeof(i));
    SampleClass* ind = reinterpret_cast<SampleClass* >(tlong);
    delete ind;
    return 0;
}
```

Now once again I realize I might've been better of using vectors & storing the pointers inside the vector. However I really wish to do this using pointers (as alternative). So can anyone tell me possible failures/better versions?

The obvious failure is if double & unsigned long long aren't the same length in size (or pointers being longer than 64 bits). Is there a method to check this at compile time? - And give a compile error in case the sizes aren't the same?

Comment: I'll eat my hat if this actually works..

Comment: I tested it basically with visual studio 2010 (though compiling for 32 bit) and it did work.. Basically the idea is to "use" the double simply to contain the data of the pointer. - It will be gibberish for double operations, however for simply casting it works.

Comment: why do you need unsigned int int? just cast it to double*?

Comment: @duedl0r: reinterprent_cast<> can only cast pointers to integer types, not to doubles. Besides if you would cast a 64-bit pointer to a double, which has 52 bits mantissa, you lose data.

Comment: since sizeof is known at compile time, you can check if sizeof( pNewObj ) fits in sizeof( double ). Should be the case on most, if not all, current compilers on both x86 and x64.

Comment: The use of `memcpy` eliminates the aliasing issues.  Intel is little endian, so __if__ portability isn't a concern, __and__ none of the addresses actually require more than 52 bits (so that the exponent is guaranteed 0), he should be able to make this work, provided the `double` are initialized to `0.0` before copying the pointer, and the copy is always for `sizeof(void*)`.  (There's no need for the intermediate `unsigned long long`.)

Comment: Why does the program have the restriction of only sending / receiving doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, at least, a 64 bit pointer, type punned to a 64 bit IEEE
double, could result in a trapping NaN, which would in turn trap.  In
practice, this might not be a problem; my attempts to get trapping NaN
to actually do something other than be ignored have not been very
successful.

Another possible problem is that the values might not be normalized
(and in fact, probably won't be).  What the hardware does with
non-normalized values depends: it could either just pass them on
transparently, silently normalize them (changing the value of the
"pointer"), or trigger some sort of runtime error.

There's also the issue of aliasing.  Accessing a pointer through an
lvalue which has a type of `double` is undefined behavior, and many
compilers will take advantage of this when optimizing, assuming that
changes through a `double*` or a `double&` reference cannot affect any
pointers (and moving the load of the pointer before the write of the
double, or not reloading the pointer after a modification of the
double).

In practice if you're working in an Intel environment, I think all
"64-bit" pointers will in fact have the upper 16 bits 0.  This is where
the exponent lives in an IEEE double, and an exponent of 0 is a gradual
underflow, which won't trap (at least with the default modes), and won't
be changes.  So your code might actually seem to work, as long as the
compiler doesn't optimize too much.

Comment: Uhm what do you mean by "values might not be normalized" - I'm sorry but my knowledge of programming hasn't reached that yet :(. A link/short explanation?   Also: would using unions prevent aliasing/optimizing problems?

Comment: @paul23 The Wikipedia has an explination of IEEE double format; in general, in most (but not all) floating point formats, values are "normalized" so that the high order digit of the mantissa is not 0.  (Now that I think about it: you can't get an unnormalized value in IEEE.  Since the base is 2, the only possible normalized high order digit is 1; because we know it's 1, there's no need to store it; the hardware inserts it implicitly.)

Comment: @paul23 With regards to aliasing: the standard isn't very clear, and compilers tend to do what they want.  The standard is clear that you can't use `union` for this; most compilers support it, however.  The one thing that is guaranteed to work is using `memcpy` between two different variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
assert(sizeof(SampleClass*) <= sizeof(unsigned long long));
assert(sizeof(unsigned long long) <= sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you'll have to test it in both 64-bit and 32-bit to make sure it works. Say it does have a different behaviour in 64-bit systems, then you could use this format to get around the problem (since you've mentioned that you're using VS2010):

```
EXPORT double InitializeClass64() {
    // Assert the pointer-size is the same as the data-type being used
    assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(double));
    // 64-bit specific code
    return ret;
}
EXPORT double DeleteClass64(double i) {
    // Assert the pointer-size is the same as the data-type being used
    assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(double));
    // 64-bit specific code
    return 0;
}

EXPORT double InitializeClass32() {
    // Assert the pointer-size is the same as the data-type being used
    assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(double));
    // 32-bit specific code
    return ret;
}
EXPORT double DeleteClass32(double i) {
    // Assert the pointer-size is the same as the data-type being used
    assert(sizeof(void*) == sizeof(double));
    // 32-bit specific code
    return 0;
}


#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_IA64)
// If it's 64-bit
#    define InitializeClass InitializeClass64
#    define DeleteClass DeleteClass64
#else
// If it's 32-bit
#    define InitializeClass InitializeClass32
#    define DeleteClass DeleteClass32
#endif // _M_X64 || _M_IA64
```

Comment: NOTE: When i say sizeof(double), it's really to validate whatever data-type you're intending to return. You could typedef this return value for different architectures, just like the last `#define` statement.